# Load prebuilt dynamic libraries from flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use my C++ library in a Flutter project. To do that I followed this guide https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop skipping the building from source part because in my case the lib is already built.

I have my `librPPG.so` at the root of my project and when I attempt to load it in `./lib/rppg_plugin.dart` like so:

```dart
final DynamicLibrary rPPGLib = Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open("../librPPG.so")
    : DynamicLibrary.open("rPPG.framework/rPPG");
```

I get thrown an error saying the lib is not found.

My question is, therefore, where should I put the `.so` lib in the project folder so I can access it. Same question for IOS with the `.framework`

Cheers!

Edit:

From the input of @igor here is my current status

`librPPG.so` in `android/src/main/jniLibs/`

in `android/build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs += 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
            }
        }
        minSdkVersion 21
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}
```

in `android/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(librPPG SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(librPPG PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/librPPG.so)
```

and the library is loaded in my plugin like so:

```dart
final DynamicLibrary rPPGLib = Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open("librPPG.so")
    : DynamicLibrary.open("rPPG.framework/rPPG");
```

when I run my code, I still get this error

```
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library (dlopen failed: library "librPPG.so" not found))
```

Answer (score -1):

For Android, create *src/main/jniLibs* folder and sub-directories for each architecture (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7). Put your .so files for each architecture. Edit *build.gradle* file of your plugin:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
}
```

In your CMakeFile specify the shared library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( librPPG SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(librPPG PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/librPPG.so)
```

If you don't need separate .so for each ABI, you can change path. Also remove '../' from `DynamicLibrary.open` call - this is a library name, not a path.

I might be wrong about iOS. To include iOS framework, add these lines to .podspec file of your plugin:

```rb
  s.preserve_paths = 'rPPG.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework rPPG' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'rPPG.framework'
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution but am still getting the same error, I updated my post with my full current setup

Comment: also, isn't the target in `CMakeLists.txt` supposed to be just `rPPG` as the lib is added automatically?